# Are solenoid's magnetic field strength more dependent upon N loops or R radius of wire?

Tags: solenoid

For a project my team and I are experimenting with different sized solenoids. We are trying to maximize the field strength exiting the end of the solenoid as opposed to internal field strength. The solenoid's equation for magnetic field strength typically describes the strength internal to the loops.

As we had tested thinner vs thicker wire, we found the thinner wire with more loops  did better than a thicker wire with less loops. If you were to have insulated wires on a nanoscale, and created a solenoid with a magnitude's worth more of loops, would you be able to create magnets capable of several Tesla?

Comment: Well... How do you calculate field strength in a solenoid?  How much resistance do you think nanoscale wires would have?  How much voltage would you need to drive such a solenoid?  How much power do you think it would dissipate?  Of course if you could cool it to superconducting temperatures you certainly could have a large field.

Comment: Metal cores like solenoids concentrate magnetic fields. The total field strength is the same with or without a metal core. So it becomes an issue of core permeability vs. saturation at high field intensities.

Comment: Did you record the current and voltage for the different wires? Will current have an effect on the field produced?

Comment: @SolarMike The measurements were only taken at 5A I believe. We didn't vary the voltage but that might be a good next step in terms of data collection. We are not experts by any means as this is for a school project.

Comment: Why don't you first work out, from theory, why you got the results you achieved? You should be able to do so. Once you understand those details, you'll also be able to see why several Tesla will be difficult, in general. See [physics of electromagnets](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/95758/213914), for example. Note that as distance extends away from the end, a third power reduction effect takes over